# Can't explain performance of Nhibernate using Guid vs. Native Keys

Tags: sql-server, performance, nhibernate, guid, increment

We've recently had the traditional and ongoing (according to SO searches) argument about assigned GUID's vs auto-increment primary keys. We are using MSSQL 2008R2, NHibernate 2.05 and .NET 4.0.

I did a fair amount of googling and reading other posts on SO about the relative insert performance difference between using the two different key types. Most of the blog posts seemed to be for fairly old versions of MSSQL server, so I thought I would try benchmarking some inserts and see if they matched what people were saying.

I wrote a simple app that just inserts 2 million objects one row per Session into the database and the only difference between the two runs of the app is the key type. Both keys are clustered - so from my reading this presents a good case for auto increments and the worst case for Guid's.

When looking at the results I was a little shocked....

Not wanting to have the reign of terror of [Zed Shaw](http://zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html) coming down on me for not perfoming a proper statistical analysis, I loaded the data into R and generated a plot (see below) and got the following summary statistics:

**GUID Keys:**

Min: 0.00

1st Quartile: 0.00

Median: 0.00

Mean: 1.975

Standard Deviation: 13.577490

3rd Quartile: 1.0

Max: 3824.0

**Native (auto-increment integer) Keys**

Min: 0.00

1st Quartile: 0.00

Median: 0.00

Mean: 1.644

Standard Deviation: 12.491320

3rd Quartile: 0.00

Max: 1932.00

Assuming that there should be a linear relationship between the size of the table and the time it takes to insert a row I tried calculating the least-squares regression, using the table size as a predictor and got the following results:

**GUID** : 0.002594

**Native**: 0.002594

The r-squared values are of the most concern to me, from my (admittedly limited) understanding of statistics there is no correlation between the size of the table and the insert speed for either case.

My concern is that the results I am getting does not correspond to the generally accepted wisdom, and I am wondering if anybody out there in SO-land can help me explain the results. I can see a few possibilities:

1. The performance problem with GUIDs was an issue with previous versions of MSSQL server, however is no longer an issue.
2. I have written a poor experiment and the results I am getting are useless.
3. A difference of 0.331 ms between is actually significant when looking at database performance and I am not considering the value reasonably.
4. The round-trip to the database to get the Id when using an auto-increment Id key does have a performance impact.
5. Using a quad-core computer for testing locally means that there is enough spare CPU to deal with the indexing in a background thread.
6. All the statistics I've seen are for raw SQL using generated GUID's and that the scenario I am testing (using NHibernate) is a different case all together.

I apologise in advance, I am not much of a database guru so I am struggling to explain these results.

Cheers,

Aidos

[image: plot]

Comment: I think I might try persisting some object graphs and test the cascade performance as well - this might help highlight some performance difference between the two key types.

Comment: Exactly what is it that are you seeking an explanation for?

Comment: Why I am not seeing the predicted insertion slowdown that a lot of blogs/SO links talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is #2, you've written an experiement which doesnt correctly reflect the conditions in 'the accepted wisdom'.  Three problems:

First you're inserting "one row per Session".  This is not the case that 'the accepted wisdom' is concerned with.  Take the documentation example of Cats, kittens and Mate where a Cat has one mate and many kittens.  Newing up and inserting whole families of cats at a time is the case thats discussed, not one row at a time.  The overhead of a transaction for each row is going to introduce a lot of noise into your test.

Second, "Assuming that there should be a linear relationship between the size of the table and the time it takes to insert a row" is also false.  The BTree structure used to hold tables has a general-case insert time of about O(log n).

Third, the reason you're seeing 'slower' inserts on guids vs identities has to do with the details of BTree.  Inserts into the middle of a tree are slower because much more data is potentially moved around and page splits are much less likely.  The guid-comb algorithm and generator was created to mitigate this problem.  Guid-comb ensures that guids created in the future will always be greater than guids created in the past thus forcing inserts to happen at the end of the table which is much more efficent.  A similar strategy is used by the newsequentialid function in sql server.

To see the predicted performance insert several hundred rows per transaction in a parent-child relationship using identity, guid and guid-comb.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! The application I have in mind doesn't need to support the "family of cats" scenario - is it only ever going to be batch inserts where the problem shows up?

Comment: I think my question would be better phrased as: In a typical web-application scenario, the system will only insert 1 or 2 rows per transaction, given your answer above, does this mean this problem won't be encountered (as there will be no bulk inserts)?

Comment: I'd be careful to generalize web applications into one-row-per-round-trip.  I've encountered plenty of web applications where 5-10 rows per round trip isn't unusual.  But if one row at a time is your only condition then yes, you wont see the issues around identities.